# A nice variety without a smooth model

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Is there a simple example of a smooth proper variety $X$ over $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$ ($p$ prime) such that

--- $X(K)\neq\emptyset$,

--- the $l$-adic étale cohomology $H^i(X\times_K\bar K,\mathbb{Q}_l)$ is unramified for every prime $l\neq p$ and every $i\in\mathbb{N}$,

--- the $p$-adic étale cohomology $H^i(X\times_K\bar K,\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is crystalline for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$,

and yet,

--- $X$ is not the generic fibre of any smooth proper $\mathbb{Z}_p$-scheme ?

[My example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416/existence-of-smooth-models/10264#10264) of a Châtelet surface with these properties is simple enough, but can one do better ?

Comment: Pedantic point: You should require that X is not the generic fiber of a smooth *proper* Z_p-scheme, or make some similar change, because X is always the generic fiber of itself, viewed as a Z_p-scheme rather than a Q_p-scheme.

Comment: When X is viewed as a Z_p-scheme, is it smooth ? But you are right, I want X to have "good reduction" in the sense of being the generic fibre of a smooth proper Z_p-scheme. Notice that every abelian Q_p-variety is the generic fibre of a smooth Z_p-scheme (for example its néronian model) but it is the generic fibre of a smooth proper Z_p-scheme only when the néronian model is an abelian scheme.

Comment: Hi Chandan! I'm a bit too lazy for a proper discussion, but were you somehow excluding a curve with tree-like reduction from your considerations? I'm sure you know that example better than I do.

Comment: @Minhyong : Ah!  You mean a curve of genus >1 which has bad reduction but whose jacobian has good reduction.  Thanks for reminding me.  Auld lang syne!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Minhyong suggests, a curve $C$ (with $C(\mathbb{Q}_p)\neq0$) which has bad reduction but whose jacobian $J$ has good reduction would do the affair.  This works because the cohomology of $C$ is essentially the same as that of $J$, and because an abelian $\mathbb{Q}_p$-variety has good reduction if and only if its $l$-adic étale cohomology is unramified for some (and hence for every) prime $l\neq p$ (Néron-Ogg-Shafarevich) or its $p$-adic étale cohomology is crystalline (Fontaine-Coleman-Iovita).

I asked Qing Liu for explicit examples.  He suggested the curve
$$
y^2=(x^3+1)(x^3+ap^6)\qquad  (a\in\mathbb{Z}_p^\times)
$$
when $p\neq2,3$, and $y^2=(x^3+x+1)(x^3+a3^4x+b3^6)$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_3^\times$, for $p=3$.

He refers to Proposition 10.3.44 in his book for computing the stable reduction of these $C$, and to Bosch-Lütkebohmert-Raynaud,
*Néron models,* Chapter 9, for showing that $J$ has good reduction.

I "accept" this answer as coming from Minhyong Kim and Qing Liu.

Answer (score 1):

Chandan, can you tell me the numbers of the theorems in Bosch-Lütkebohmert-Raynaud?

Comment: I don't have a copy of the book, but Liu was referring to Raynaud's results relating the Néron model of $J$ to the Picard scheme of a regular proper model of $C$.

Comment: How does one calculate defining equations for tha Picard scheme or the Néron model?

Comment: The redution of $J$: Chapter 9, Example 9.2/8, page 246. 